Sending video notes to multiple users using Telegram Bot API results in 404 error for subsequent requests
I'm trying to send a video note to multiple Telegram users using the Telegram Bot API, but I'm encountering an issue where the first request succeeds and all subsequent requests return a 404 "Not Found" error. Here's the PHP code I'm using to send these video notes:
$apiURLBase = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<YourBotToken>/";
$selectedUsers = ['111111111', '2222222222']; // Example chat IDs
$originalVideoPath = 'path_to_your_video.mp4';

foreach ($selectedUsers as $chatId) {
    $uniqueFilePath = 'video_notes/' . uniqid() . '.mp4';
    copy($originalVideoPath, $uniqueFilePath); // Ensure a unique file for each request

    $apiURL = $apiURLBase . "sendVideoNote";
    $video_note = new CURLFile($uniqueFilePath);

    $data = [
        'chat_id' => $chatId,
        'video_note' => $video_note
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    unlink($uniqueFilePath); // Clean up the temporary file

    echo "Response for chat_id $chatId: " . $output . "<br>";
}

Expected behavior:
I expect the video note to be sent to all users in the $selectedUsers array without any issues.
Actual behavior:
The first user in the array receives the video note successfully, but for the second user, I receive the following response from the Telegram API:

{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}

Additional details:
The video files are ensured to be unique for each request by copying them to a new file with a unique name.
The problem persists even after adding a delay between requests using sleep(1);.
All other parameters and settings (such as API URLs, bot token, etc.) have been double-checked for accuracy.
Could anyone help identify why subsequent requests are failing and how to fix this issue?

If I truly understand your need - you may try using rename instead of performing copy + unlink so as to avoid IO bottleneck (especially this time we are talking about a mp4 movie file)
